# Testing method called on Sinon.js spy

Tags: javascript, sinon

I am using SinonJS to test that my controller calls methods in my view. I want to test that the `addSeat` method is called with a value of `testSeat`. My best effort is what is in the code below but I am getting an error. I want to be able to test this without having the bring my view module into my tests. Is this possible?

```
describe('Adding a seat', function() {
  view1Spy = {
        addSeat: sinon.spy(),
        render: sinon.spy()
  };
  beforeEach(function() {
    newSeat = seatingChartController.addSeat(3, 4);
    seatingChartController.registerView(view1Spy);
  });
  it('Calls addSeat on each view with the added seat', function() {
    expect(view1Spy.addSeat).to.be.calledWith(newSeat);
  });
}
```

EDIT:

This is the error:

```
1) Seating Chart Controller Adding a seat Calls addSeat on each view with the added seat
     Failure/Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'expect(view1Spy.addSeat).to.be.calledWith(newSeat)'
```

Comment: What's the error? Not much good if we don't know that :)

Comment: What's the `expect` module you're using -- chai?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in this case you'd want something like:

```js
view1Spy = {addSeat: sinon.spy()};
// ...
expect(view1Spy.addSeat.calledWith(newSeat)).to.be.true;
```

Comment: Yeah, either that or instantiate a real view and `sinon.stub()` its `addSeat` method.

Comment: @robertklep Right -- this accomplishes what OP wanted in terms of not having to involve the view class in the test.

Comment: Nice! That makes sense, but now I am getting a different error - I posted the updated code and error in the post.

Comment: @ThomYorkkke Please take a look at the updated answer and see if it resolves the second issue.

Comment: @JMM That's perfect. Thank you. Can I not use .to.be.calledWith?

Comment: @ThomYorkkke I don't think you can do that because there's a method `sinon.spy().calledWith()`, but `expect()` returns an object that has properties and methods of the expect module, unless the module you're using provides some special handling that would make that work.